# SSIS Flat File Missing First Column

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm trying to import flat file using SSIS. This is the structure of the flat file:

```
HEADER001
1|2|3|4
5|6|7|8
```

I want to skip the header, already set the Header rows to skip to 1 and unchecked the Column names in the first data row.

[image: Flat File Connection Manager 1]

Somehow the first column will disappear. I've tried to change the row delimiter to {CR} or {LF} but nothing different.
[image: Flat File Connection Manager 2]

Anybody know how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: WHat if you change the "Header Row delimiter to line break instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the Header Row delimiter to {CR}{LF} instead of Vertical Bar. When you say the header row delimiter should be a vertical bar (and it should be skipped)  it removes everything before the first |

[image: Like this]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

script component source:

```
var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines([filePath]);

int ctr=0;

foreach(var line in lines)
{
   ctr++;
   if(ctr!=1)
   {
      string[] cols = line.Split('|');
      Output0Buffer.AddRow();
      OutputBuffer0.Col1 = (int)cols[0];
      OutputBuffer0.Col2 = (int)cols[1];
      OutputBuffer0.Col3 = (int)cols[2];
      OutputBuffer0.Col4 = (int)cols[3];
   }
}
```